# twitter timeline dynamic search query in version 1.1

Tags: search, dynamic, twitter, timeline

In twitter v1.1 it is not possible anymore to create dynamic search queries for the timeline widget. So what possibilities do we have?

1. Editors will have to create the appropriate widgets (with search queries) in twitter and fill in the ids in the cms. Which means editors have to maintain widgets in 2 places.
2. Use rest api so search and show tweets, thus getting the tweets from twitter and custom showing on frontend. Lot more development work and it seems that the twitter search api will not return all results the readymade widget would return, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets ("Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.")
3. Creating widgets possible from apis? Then we could create the widgets from cms and save the ids (from twitter) and in portal use those ids to show. Is this possible with the twitter api? What are the capabilities, so can we edit a widget after creation for example, etc.

What path would be recommened?